# How to purge data in elasticsearch index using query in curl

Tags: curl, elasticsearch

I am trying to delete some part of data in the elasticsearch index using `curl`. I am trying to delete it based on the timestamp query(like to purge the data from certain time). I have tried the below query but its deleting the complete data in the index.

```
curl -XDELETE 'http://beepal1.tms.toyota.com:9200/logstash-sys_timestamp' -d '
{
  "query": 
  {
    "range": 
                {
      "@timestamp": 
                  { 
                  "gte": "2016-05-27T07:00:00.000Z",
                  "lte": "2016-05-28T06:59:59.999Z"
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

I don't know where I am going wrong.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install the [delete by query plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/2.3/plugins-delete-by-query.html) first and then you can run this:

```
curl -XDELETE 'http://beepal1.tms.toyota.com:9200/logstash-sys_timestamp/_query' -d '
{
  "query": 
  {
    "range": 
                {
      "@timestamp": 
                  { 
                  "gte": "2016-05-27T07:00:00.000Z",
                  "lte": "2016-05-28T06:59:59.999Z"
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

Comment: I am getting this message but the data didn't get deleted. `{"took":200,"timed_out":false,"_indices":{"_all":{"found":0,"deleted":0,"missing":0,"failed":0}},"failures":[]}`

Comment: That probably means no data matches your query. can you try to increase the date interval?